# What is Type ev.R?

Tags: scala, types, cassandra, expression, datastax-java-driver

I have a ResultSet which is `com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet` from which I am taking the ExecutionInfo and from the executionInfo I am extracting the queryTrace as you can see the following code.

```
resultSet.getAllExecutionInfo.forEach { exeInfo: ExecutionInfo =>
        val queryTimeTaken: FiniteDuration = exeInfo.getQueryTrace.getDurationMicros.microsecond  //this works fine if i do getDurationMicros microsecond it return ev.R
        exeInfo.getQueryTrace.getEvents.forEach { event =>
          if (queryTimeTaken > timeTakenLimit) {
            TraceLogger.info {
              s"DateTime = ${sdf.format {event.getTimestamp}} Description = ${event.getDescription}  " +
                s"TimeElapsedMicro = ${event.getSourceElapsedMicros} Statement = ${exeInfo.getStatement}" +
                s" TimeTaken =$queryTimeTaken"
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

in the second line of the code which is

**val queryTimeTaken:FiniteDuration=exeInfo.getQueryTrace.getDurationMicros.microsecond**

when i am doing `getDurationMicros.microsecond` it return Object of FiniteDuration but if i do `getDurationMicros microsecond` it return `ev.R` type
can someone please explan why it is retrning such type. What difference the space is making in these two lines?

Is it something related to the postfix expression evaluation?

**Edit one :**

```
def a = 500
val x: FiniteDuration = a.microsecond // this works fine
val y: FiniteDuration = 500 microsecond

def a = 500
val x: ev.R = a.microsecond() // this gives ev.R
val y: FiniteDuration = 500 microsecond

def a = 500
val x: FiniteDuration  = a microsecond // this works fine
val y: FiniteDuration = 500 microsecond
```

Comment: Are you sure you're calling it like this: `val queryTimeTaken: FiniteDuration = exeInfo.getQueryTrace.getDurationMicros microsecond`? Because I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes i am sure i am calling it like this only you can reproduce it by the second example you can see in Edit One.

Comment: Your second example explicitly asks requires the return type to be `ev.R`, they are not equivalent.

Comment: i will update the question with the more code, because i am sure it's like this only getDurationMicros microsecond

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i checked once more and yes i am using it like this only exeInfo.getQueryTrace.getDurationMicros microsecond and it's casuing me the error i am using scala 2.12.1